Problema con Filtro de Dia, Semana, Mes
Hola Espero que se encuentren muy bien. Tengo varios contenedores con datos que se registran por fecha. He creado un filtro, pero al preionar TODO se ven todos los registros, pero con los botones de Dia, Semana y Mes me dicen que no hay registros.
He probado cambiando el formato de fecha, pero los botones de Dia, Semana y Mes siguen sin encontrar los registros. Llevo horas intentando y nada, he incluso traté de que ChatGPT me resolviera el problema pero cada solución que genera da el mismo resultado y no muestra nada. Gracias de antemano.
function setFiltro(filtro){
// Filtra los elementos basados en el filtro seleccionado
const filtrarPorFecha = (item) => {
// Obtener la fecha de hoy en formato dd/mm/yyyy
  const fechaHoy = (() => {
    const today = new Date();
    const day = today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');// Añadir un 0 si el día es de un solo dígito.
    const month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');  // Añadir un 0 si el mes es de un solo dígito
    const year = today.getFullYear();
    return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
  })();

  // Normalizamos la fecha de creación del viaje al formato dd/mm/yyyy
  const fechaCreacion = item.fechaCreacion;// Usamos directamente la fecha de creación del viaje.
  const fechaCreacionNormalizada = fechaCreacion;// El formato ya es dd/mm/yyyy

  // Filtrar según el filtro seleccionado
  switch (filtro) {
    case 'TODO':
      return true; // No filtrar, mostrar todo
    case 'DIA':
      return fechaHoy === fechaCreacionNormalizada; // Compara solo la fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy
    case 'SEMANA':
    // Obtener el primer día de la semana
      const inicioSemana = new Date();
      inicioSemana.setDate(inicioSemana.getDate() - inicioSemana.getDay());// Primer día de la semana (domingo)
      const finSemana = new Date(inicioSemana);
      finSemana.setDate(inicioSemana.getDate()+6);// Último día de la semana (sábado)

      // Convertir el inicio y fin de la semana al formato dd/mm/yyyy
      const inicioSemanaNormalizada = (() => {
        const day = inicioSemana.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const month = (inicioSemana.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const year = inicioSemana.getFullYear();
        return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
      })();

      const finSemanaNormalizada = (() => {
        const day = finSemana.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const month = (finSemana.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const year = finSemana.getFullYear();
        return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
      })();

      return fechaCreacionNormalizada >= inicioSemanaNormalizada && fechaCreacionNormalizada <= finSemanaNormalizada; // Dentro de la misma semana
    case 'MES':
    // Compara mes y año
      const mesHoy = fechaHoy.slice(3, 5); // Extrae el mes de la fecha actual
      const mesCreacion = fechaCreacion.slice(3, 5); // Extrae el mes de la fecha de creación

      const anioHoy = fechaHoy.slice(6); // Extrae el año de la fecha actual
      const anioCreacion = fechaCreacion.slice(6); // Extrae el año de la fecha de creación
    
      return mesHoy === mesCreacion && anioHoy === anioCreacion; // Mismo mes y año
    default:
      return true;
  }
};
    
  // Crear los botones de filtro
 return (
   <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#222' : '#f9f9f9' }]}>
     <Text style={[styles.title, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#333' }]}>Ingresos</Text>

     <View style={styles.filtroContainer}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFiltro('TODO')}>
         <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }]}>TODO</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFiltro('DIA')}>
         <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }]}>DÍA</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFiltro('SEMANA')}>
         <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }]}>SEMANA</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFiltro('MES')}>
         <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }]}>MES</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>

     {organizarPorFecha(filtrarViajes()).length === 0 ? (
       <Text style={[styles.noTrips, { color: isDarkMode ? '#aaa' : '#000' }]}>No hay viajes registrados.</Text>
      ) : (
      <FlatList
        data={organizarPorFecha(filtrarViajes()).filter(filtrarPorFecha)} // Aplica el filtro
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
        // Obtener la fecha de creación
          const fechaCreacion = (() => {
           const today = new Date();
           const day = today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');  // Añade un 0 si el día es de un solo dígito
           const month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');  // Añade un 0 si el mes es de un solo dígito
           const year = today.getFullYear();
           return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
        })();

        // Buscar el total de gastos para la fecha de este item
        const totalGastosDia = totalesPorFecha.find(
          (total) => total.fecha === item.fecha
        )?.total || 0;

        return (
          <View style={[styles.fechaContainer, { backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#333' : '#fff' }]}>
          {/* Titulo de la fecha de creación del contenedor */}
          <Text style={[styles.fechaTitle, { color: isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#000' }]}>
            {fechaCreacion} - Viajes: {item.viajes.length} - Neto: ${item.totales.neto.toFixed(2)}
          </Text>

          {/* Contenedor de totales */}
          <View style={[styles.summaryContainer, { backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#333' : '#f9f9f9' }]}>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Monto Cobrado: ${item.totales.montoCobrado.toFixed(2)}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Kilometraje: {item.totales.kilometraje.toFixed(2)} km</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Comisión: ${item.totales.comision.toFixed(2)}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Gastos Fijos: ${item.totales.gastosFijos.toFixed(2)}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Tiempo Total: {Math.floor(item.totales.duracionTotal / 60)}h {item.totales.duracionTotal % 60}m</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Costo por Km: ${calcularCostoPorKm(item.totales)}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.summaryText, { color: isDarkMode ? '#ddd' : '#000' }]}>Gastos del Día: ${totalGastosDia}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.fecha}
    />
    )}
  </View>
  );

};



Que vale fechaCreacion? intenta un console.log(fechaHoy+"=="+fechaCreacionNormalizada), a ver que te sale.

intenta testear la app, creo que te será mas facil conseguir el error (testear es modificar las condiciones a la que espera probar a cada función y ver si la funcion hace lo que se espera que hace, ejemplo: function returnTrue(is_one){return is_one==1;} function test_returnTrue(){const result=[returnTrue(0),returnTrue(1),returnTrue("hola")], esperado=[false,true,false];for (let i=0;i<result.length;i++)if (result[i]!=esperado)console.log("Ha ocurrido un error en el caso "+i+".");} test_returnTrue();
